# Is a massive parachute coming out from an ejectable fuselage technically possible for a commercial aircraft?

Tags: safety, airline-operations, airframe-parachute

And would it save lives?

This video quotes no sources (except the usual "someone") but has gone viral:

https://www.facebook.com/ScienceNaturePage/videos/761924050606522/

Comment: The question was on "skeptics". Feel free to remove it, as it does indeed seem a duplicate.

Comment: This question, *"Is [it] technically possible..."*, varies from the question of  *"Why don't commercial jet aircraft have a parachute escape system?"*. Though that question is unquestionably related, I would expect to see different answers here.

Comment: I am the OP and I think there is no difference whatsoever. The wording is different but my question is greatly answered there. The only reason why I posted it is that on "skeptics" I couldn't find anything similar, and I didn't remember of "Aviation".